# React Js state error (Cannot update during an existing state)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I wanted to set state for logged in user if user not logged in then navigate is true by this.setstate() method. but problem its showing error at console and not working the process here is error bellow

```
0.chunk.js:219252 Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.
in Header (at App.js:9)
in App (at src/index.js:17)
in ErrorBoundary (at src/index.js:16)
in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
in BrowserRouter (at src/index.js:15)
```

Here bellow my app.js code

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.scss';
import Header from './components/Header/Header';
import Sidebar from './components/Sidebar/Sidebar';
import Routes from './routes/Routes';
function App() {
return (
<>
  <Header />
  <Sidebar />
  <Routes />
</>
); 
}

export default App;
```

Signin.js code

```
export default class SignIn extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        redirect: false, 
    };
 }
}

render() {
   if (this.state.redirect) {
        return <Redirect to="/" />;
    }
    
}

onSignInHandler = () => {
   .......
   this.setState({
                    ....
                    redirect: true,
                });
}
```

At Header.js where logout button have. I wanted to give this link onclick() handler. here below are code

```
export default class Header extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        navigate: false
    }
   }

   onLogoutHandler = () => {
    ....
    this.setState({
        navigate: true,
    });
   };

  render() {
     const { navigate } = this.state;
    if (navigate) {
        return <Redirect to="/signin" push={true} />;
    }
    return(<header></header>)
  }
  
}
```

At header.js I have logout link which will trigger  the onLogoutHandler and state will then will redirect to signin page. please help me for this issue

Comment: The problem is while your state is setting in onSignInHandler, your render is called as well and that is why it says Cannot update during an existing state transition. setState is asynchronous and while it is transitioning your render is called to redirect. I would suggest you pass redirect as props and navigate according to it.

Comment: please show me how can id do this

Comment: Pls make onLogoutHandler function async and this.setState({ navigate: true }); await as await this.setState({ navigate: true }); and see if it works. You got to debug here. Pls try this and see if it works

Comment: please give an answer with the code accordingly

Comment: these snippets are good and are not cause of the issue. Can you at least have whole of render function, so we can help, otherwise code snippets provided are fine. Also, you can check those line numbers in error `in Header (at App.js:9)
in App (at src/index.js:17)`, they can help you better

Answer (score 0):

Please check if this works

```
onLogoutHandler = async () => {
....
await this.setState({
    navigate: true,
});
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have `return` statement at the end of your `render()` method from your class component

```
  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.state;
    if (navigate) {
      return <Redirect to="/signin" push={true} />;
    }
    // you should also have return statement in this line here
    // return something like
    return null;
  }
```

Comment: hi Rehan, I am returning my html at there please check my code again

Comment: @mdkamrul I see that it was outside of your render method.

Comment: sorry was mistake check now please